# SharePoint 2010 Search Errors

Tags: 2010, search, web-analytics

I am unable to get SharePoint 2010 native search & Analytics working:

The EventViewer on Server for Search, Analysis report & some other issues has following information:

1. An exception occurred when trying to issue security token:

> The security token username and password could not be validated.

2. A WebHost HTTP exception occurred.

> Sender Information:
>       System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/33711845
>       HtmlErrorMessage:

Can someone please help me on this...

Comment: 1] This error is not related to your search issues. To fix this go to the SP hive \14\template\controltemplates -then open the taxonomypicker.ascx and replace the string &#44; with a comma (,) Then save the file. Error wont occur again.

Comment: 2] This error is not neccessary related to you search issues. Have a look at the blog post to resolve that error: http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/10/06/resolving-the-super-user-account-utilized-by-the-cache-is.aspx